# How to draw custom shapes in LibGDX by path?

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx, shapes

Consider I have to create a custom/complex shape composed by some elements, inluding lines, rects and/or curves (bezier, cubic...). In standard Java we have the Path2D element, which allows us to perform some of those elements by going through predefined points. The following method demonstrates a simple approach to return a `path` by some points:

```
    private Path2D aShape(double x, double y) {
        ArrayList<double[]> points = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new double[]{x, y},
                        new double[]{x - (L * 0.2588190451), y - (L * 0.4482877361)},
                        new double[]{x, y - (L * 0.7071067812)},
                        new double[]{x + (L * 0.2588190451), y - (L * 0.4482877361)}));

        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.moveTo(points.get(0)[0], points.get(0)[1]);
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); ++i) {
            //line or anything avaliable...
            path.lineTo(points.get(i)[0], points.get(i)[1]);
        }
        path.closePath();

        return path;
    }
```

After, this method can be drawn by a `Graphics2D`. However, I din't found (yet, at least) any element that works in this way or even a element that supplies functions to draw curves or something like that, as Path2D, in LibGDX library.

For my tests I'm trying to draw a [music treble_clef](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/26/01/17/treble-clef-1279909_960_720.png) by following path, but didn't found a trick to do that.

What could be a approach to perform custom shape drawing in LibGDX by a passed path?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **ShapeRenderer**. It has methods for drawing lines, arcs, rects an so on.

[Docs are here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Rendering-shapes),